# Parse.com php exception shows all errors

Tags: php, parse-platform

When i try to run php code using Parse.com PHP SDK it 
the error is "Account already exists for this username"

but it throw all this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Parse\ParseException' with message 'Account already exists for this username' in /Users/yousef/Desktop/project/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:357 Stack trace: #0 /Users/yousef/Desktop/project/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(1038): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', 'classes/_User', NULL, '{"username":"my...', false) #1 /Users/yousef/Desktop/project/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php(947): Parse\ParseObject::deepSave(Object(Parse\ParseUser), false) #2 /Users/yousef/Desktop/project/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseUser.php(108): Parse\ParseObject->save() #3 /Users/yousef/Desktop/project/test.php(20): Parse\ParseUser->signUp() #4 {main} thrown in /Users/yousef/Desktop/project/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 357
```

The Code i Use

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Parse\ParseClient;

ParseClient::initialize('YousefId', '', 'YousefMaster');
ParseClient::setServerURL('server-ip:1337/parse');


use Parse\ParseUser;

$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", "my name");
$user->set("password", "my pass");
$user->set("email", "email@example.com");
$user->set("phone", "415-392-0202");

try {
  $user->signUp();
} catch (ParseException $error) {
    echo $error->getCode();
    echo $error->getMessage();
}

?>
```

so how do i just show the error code and message instead of showing all this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the `ParseException` within the `Parse` namespace.

Try

```
catch (Parse\ParseException $error) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue, and i don't think this is the issue because on [Github](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk) the Parse PHP SDK using it as i did.

Comment: oh, sorry it worked i typed it wrong in my code, so yea ur code is working fine which made me wonder why on github say's different.

Comment: Probably the documentation is slightly out of date. Maybe you can submit a pull request to fix it!

Comment: I had a look at the documentation and they don't specifically mention namespacing. An alternate fix which would replicate the code they have in their documentation would be to add a namespace definition of `namespace Parse` at the top of the file.

Comment: `user Parse` where exactly ? u mean instead of `use Parse/ParseClient` ?